# Naming a restricted probability space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$.

I want to consider $(\Omega',F',P')$, where $\Omega'\subset\Omega$ is nonempty event such that $P(\Omega')>0$, and $F'=\{\omega\cap\Omega'\mid\omega\in F\}$, and $P'(\omega')=P(\omega\cap\Omega')/P(\Omega')$.

Then, this would be a probability space and I believe there should be a name to call this.

**Question**: How do we call this space?

Comment: There is no specific name. I would call it the probability space induce by $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ on $\Omega '$.

Comment: @Surb - I see. Thank you!

Comment: Some people call this the trace of $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ on $\Omega'$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - Thanks a lot!